# My long SWI-Prolog grammar keeps on failing

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

My long grammar keeps on failing.

It recognizes text in the form `a.\n a.` and is supposed to return a list of sentences, spaces and returns.

`test//1` is the main grammar that calls the other rules and compiles the output.

`sentence32//1` and `sentence33//1` recognizes the letters, etc. in the sentence.

`spaces//1` and `returns//1` recognize the space and returns respectively.

`sentenceendpunctuation//1` parses the end of sentence punctuation.

Here it is:

```
use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

test([]) --> [].  
test(AAs) --> 
  spaces(Y), 
  {
    string_length(Y,YLen),
    (
      YLen>0->Start = [[s,YLen]]
    ;
      Start=[]
    )
  }, 
  sentence32(X),
  returns(Z),
  {
    [XS] = X,
    string_length(XS,XLen),
    (
      XLen>0->append(Start,[X],Next)
    ;
      Next=Start
    ), 
    string_length(Z,ZLen),
    (
      ZLen>0->append(Next,[[r,ZLen]],Last)
    ;
      Last=Next
    )
  },
  test(As),
  {
    append(Last,As,AAs)
  },
  !. 

test(Last) --> 
  spaces(Y), 
  {
    string_length(Y,YLen),
    (
      YLen>0->Start = [[s,YLen]]
    ;
      Start=[])
  }, 
  sentence32(X),
  returns(Z),
  {
    [XS] = X,
    string_length(XS,XLen),
    (
      XLen>0->append(Start,[X],Next)
    ;
      Next=Start
    ),
    string_length(Z,ZLen),
    (
      ZLen>0->append(Next,[[r,ZLen]],Last)
    ;
      Last=Next)
    },
    !.

spaces(XXs) --> 
  [X], 
  {
    X=32
  },
  spaces(Xs),
  {
    char_code(Ch,X),
    atom_string(CA,Ch),
    atom_concat(CA,Xs,XXs)
  },
  !.
spaces('') --> [].

returns(XXs) --> 
  [X], 
  {
    X=10
  }, 
  returns(Xs),
  {
    char_code(Ch,X),
    atom_string(CA,Ch),
    atom_concat(CA,Xs,XXs)
  },
  !.
returns('') --> [].

sentence32([XsZ]) -->
  sentence33(Xs), 
  sentenceendpunctuation(Z),
  {
    atom_string(CA,Xs),
    atom_concat(CA,Z,XsZ)
  }, 
  !.
sentence32('') --> [].

sentence33(CXs) --> 
  [X],
  {
    (
      (
        char_type(X,alnum)
      ;
        char_type(X,white)
      )
    ;
      char_type(X,punct)
    ),
    not(X=93),
    char_code(C,X),
    not(X=91),
    not(X=46),
    not(X=33),
    not(X=63),
    not(X=10)
  },
  sentence33(Xs),
  {
    atom_string(CA,C),
    atom_concat(CA,Xs,CXs)
  },
  !. 
sentence33('') --> [].

sentenceendpunctuation(Z) --> 
  [Z1],
  {
    char_code(Z,Z1),
    (
      Z='.'
    ;
      (
        Z='?'
      ;
        (
           Z='!'
        )
      )
    )
  },
  !.
```

When I enter the query to parse my string

```
string_codes(" a. a.",Y),phrase(test(X),Y).
```

I get `false.`

Comment: Are their more details about the failure? Usually people here want to see actual results and/or error messages.

Comment: Related question: [I can't get my Prolog DCG working for spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54374105/1243762)

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: My long grammar keeps on failing

I just commented out the base case!!!!

```
%% test([]) --> [].
```

I get

```
?- string_codes(" a. a.",Y),phrase(test(X),Y).
Y = [32, 97, 46, 32, 97, 46],
X = [[s, 1], ['a.'], [s, 1], ['a.']].
```