# I can't get my Prolog DCG working with atom concat

Tags: prolog, dcg

I can't get this Prolog DCG code working:

```
String1="   ",string_codes(String1,Codes),phrase(spaces(Output),Codes).

spaces(XXs) -->
   [X], {X=32}, spaces(Xs),
   {char_code(Ch,X), atom_concat(Ch,Xs,XXs)}, !. %%Space
spaces([]) --> [].
```

Comment: Be careful with this if you latter add `set_prolog_flags(double_quotes, <somevalue>).` It can mess up your whole week.

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog DCG Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg)

Answer (score 2):

I feel like an improved solution would probably be something like this:

```
spaces(Spaces) --> " ", spaces(S0), { atom_concat(' ', S0, Spaces) }.
spaces('') --> [].
```

There's no real need to ask what the char is for code 32, you know it's a space. Also, `[X], {X=32}` from your answer is better as `[32]`, which is still better as `" "`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing [] in the base case to ''.

```
spaces(XXs) -->
   [X], {X=32}, spaces(Xs),
   {char_code(Ch,X), atom_concat(Ch,Xs,XXs)}, !. %% Space
spaces('') --> [].

String1 = "   ",
Codes = [32, 32, 32],
Output = '   '.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing DCG and using SWI-Prolog there is a library of often used predicates and DCG clauses in [dcgbasics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=summary-lib-dcgbasics). This can be used in code with

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
```

To list the code for the predicates use [listing/1](http://:-%20use_module(library(dcg/basics)).), e.g.

```
?- listing(dcg_basics:_).
```

The library has a DCG clause `blanks//0` that does what you want, e.g.

```
?- listing(dcg_basics:blanks).
blanks(A, B) :-
    blank(A, C),
    !,
    D=C,
    blanks(D, B).
blanks(A, A).

true.

?- listing(dcg_basics:blank).
blank([C|A], B) :-
    nonvar(C),
    code_type(C, space),
    B=A.

true.
```

which as DCG is

```
blank -->
    [C],
    {
        nonvar(C),
        code_type(C,space)
    }.

blanks -->
    blank, !, blanks.

blanks --> [].
```

NB
The library version uses `character codes` and not `characters`.

```
?- string_codes("",Codes),phrase(blanks,Codes,Rest).
Codes = Rest, Rest = [].

?- string_codes(" ",Codes),phrase(blanks,Codes,Rest).
Codes = [32],
Rest = [].

?- string_codes("  ",Codes),phrase(blanks,Codes,Rest).
Codes = [32, 32],
Rest = [].

?- string_codes("   ",Codes),phrase(blanks,Codes,Rest).
Codes = [32, 32, 32],
Rest = [].
```