# How can I save and load data files in Prolog?

Tags: file, prolog

How can I quickly save and load data files in Prolog, for use with games?

Save files with save(File_name,Term), where File_name is the file name in folder folder_name and Term is a compound containing the data file.

```
?- save("file_name.txt",[[["player_name","Harold"],["score",10],["symbol",key_word]],[["player_name","Queenie"],["score",20],["symbol",schema]]]).
```

Load files with load(File_name,Term), where File_name is the file name in folder folder_name and Term is the contents loaded from the file.

```
?- load("file_name.txt",Term),writeln1(Term).
Term=[[["player_name","Harold"],["score",10],["symbol",key_word]],[["player_name","Queenie"],["score",20],["symbol",schema]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to save a single term, a basic version of what you want is the following:

```
save(Filename, Term) :-
    open(Filename, write, Stream),
    write_canonical(Stream, Term),
    write(Stream, '.'),
    close(Stream).

load(Filename, Term) :-
    open(Filename, read, Stream),
    read(Stream, Term),
    close(Stream).
```

For example:

```
?- save('hello.term', hello(world)).
true.
```

At this point the file `hello.term` (the name is arbitrary) contains this:

```
hello(world).
```

Then:

```
?- load('hello.term', Term).
Term = hello(world).
```

Notes:

- The `read` predicates expect to read a term with a terminating period (`.`), but the `write` predicates don't write those out by themselves. Therefore `save/2` needs to write it explicitly.
- There is no error handling here.
- There is also a `write/2` predicate that could be used. The difference is relevant if you use operators: The term `a + b` will be written as `a + b` by `write` and as `+(a, b)` by `read`. The latter can be read correctly even in cases where the write and the read happen with different operator declarations.
- More work is needed if you want to write or read multiple terms.

Comment: Don't bother with OP, they have a thing where they ask questions and then answer them. Our efforts to help only get in the way of whatever OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: From OP's own convoluted answer it looks like they themselves are getting in their own way ;-) The question itself is valid, and something that others can legitimately want to know, so I think it's good for the community to have a proper answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below you can save and load data files in Prolog.

```
% save("file_name.txt",[[["player_name","Harold"],["score",10],["symbol",key_word]],[["player_name","Queenie"],["score",20],["symbol",schema]]]).

save(File_name,Term) :-
    string_concat("folder_name/",File_name,Path),
    term_to_atom(Term,Atom),
    string_atom(String,Atom),
    (open_s(Path,write,Stream1),
    write(Stream1,String),
    close(Stream1)),!.

% load("file_name.txt",Term).

load(File_name,Term) :-
    File_name="file_name.txt",
    string_concat("folder_name/",File_name,Path),
    phrase_from_file_s(string(Codes),Path),
    string_codes(String,Codes),
    atom_to_term(String,Term,[]).

open_s(File,Mode,Stream) :-
    atom_string(File1,File),
    open(File1,Mode,Stream),!.

string_atom(String,Atom) :-
    atom_string(Atom,String),!.

phrase_from_file_s(string(Output), String) :-
    atom_string(String1,String),
    phrase_from_file(string(Output), String1),!.

string(String) --> list(String).

list([]) --> [].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).
    
writeln1(Term) :-
    term_to_atom(Term,Atom),
    writeln(Atom),!.
```

See also string to list ([Test 15](https://github.com/luciangreen/listprologinterpreter/blob/master/lpiverify4.pl)) in List Prolog, which does the same thing as atom_to_term//3.  The predicates above replace the need for using long grammars, however I have posted answers on [My long SWI-Prolog grammar keeps on failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559339/my-long-swi-prolog-grammar-keeps-on-failing) and [I can't get my Prolog DCG working with atom concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374105/i-cant-get-my-prolog-dcg-working-with-atom-concat) for those who are interested.

Comment: In the save//2 predicate, Stream1 must be different (i.e. Stream2, etc.) for each file saved.